# scrollview within ViewPager ,ViewPager within RecyclerView conflicts

Tags: android

I need the whole layout can scroll vertically,when i choose the ScrollView as the root view,the bottom view cant be calculated the whole height accurately(btw,RecyclerView in ViewPager I override the canScrollVertically() and return false,cause only whole layout can scroll vertically), how should i solve it?

So bad,i don't have 10 reputation ,can't post images
here is the link:

https://github.com/liuhuibin/TaoBaoProgressBar/blob/master/.raw/q.png

Comment: This is a sample app showing viewpager,recycle view and tab view together,This may help https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: thx,but the whole fragment should be scrollable vertically like ListView